# Which 'for' loops for the following permutation?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, permutation

I'm trying to obtain these permutations with a for loop.

- 2 elements {a,b} result:

  a, b, ab
- 3 elements {a,b,c} result:

  a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc
- 4 elements {a,b,c,d} result:

  a, b, c, d, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd, abc, abd, acd, bcd, abcd
- 5 elements {a,b,c,d,e} result:

  a, b, c, d, e, ab, ac, ad, ae, bc, bd, be, cd, ce, de, abc, abd, abe,
  acd, ace, ade, bcd, bce, bde, cde, abcd, abce, abde, acde, bcde,
  abcde

and so on.

I've done this in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neuran/0gd1qprz/), laying down `for` loops one after another to catch a systematic structure:

```
var a, b, c;

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
b = [];

for(i=0; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = a[i];
}
for(i=1; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[0]+b[i];
}
for(i=2; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[1]+b[i];
}
for(i=3; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[2]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[3]+b[i];
}
for(i=2; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[5]+b[i];
}
for(i=3; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[6]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[7]+b[i];
}
for(i=3; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[9]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[10]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[12]+b[i];
}
for(i=3; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[15]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[16]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[18]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[21]+b[i];
}
for(i=4; i < a.length; i++){
  b[b.length] = b[25]+b[i];
}
```

Comment: The logic is not clear. Why did you chose those particular permutations out of the logically possible permutations?

Comment: @sawa the logic here, I guess, is that the order doesn't matter: so, for instance, for two elements there are only 3 results because `ab === ba` (in that case that's not a permutation). This is a wild guess, and of course we answerers should not be guessing... voting to close as *unclear*.

Comment: That is not permutation.

Comment: That is the powerset. The set of all subsets of a set.

Comment: The logic is clear, no elements repeated, just one order for element. You can think of a sort n^n with increasing [i+1] objects into combinations and a n!.

Comment: @DanD. is right.

Comment: Check for a recursive function the solution you posted is not dynamic, i will try to check for an answer later

Comment: There should be possible to downvote who downvote because don't understand.

Comment: If you want them in that order, you need to use the banker's sequence. See https://www.google.com/search?q=subsets+banker http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf http://www.thelowlyprogrammer.com/2010/04/indexing-and-enumerating-subsets-of.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution.

```js
var x = ['a','b','c','d'],
 possiblePermutation = [];

x.forEach(function(elmt){
 possiblePermutation.push(elmt)
 var rest = x.slice( x.indexOf(elmt) + 1);
 myPermutationGeneration(elmt,rest)
})
function myPermutationGeneration(current,rest){ 
 rest.forEach( function( restEle ){
  possiblePermutation.push( current + restEle )
  var rest2 = x.slice( x.indexOf(restEle) + 1);
  myPermutationGeneration( current + restEle, rest2)
 })
}
console.log( possiblePermutation )
```

Comment: thats what i meant nice answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one that might work.

```js
var getCombinations = function(arr, originalLength) {
 if (originalLength == 0) return arr;
 var diff = arr.length - originalLength;
 var l = arr.length;
 var result = arr;
 for (i=0; i < originalLength; i++){
   for (j=diff+i; j < l; j++) {
  if (!arr[j].includes(arr[i]))
   result.push(arr[i] + arr[j]);
   }
 }
 return getCombinations(result, originalLength - 1);
}

var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
console.log(getCombinations(a, a.length));
```